# Comparing 2 images pixel by pixel (the first image is stored at a database)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to compare 2 images, where the first image is stored in a database and the second image is from a live video stream via a webcam. Is it possible to determine whether there are some differences between the images, or whether they are identical?

I want the image comparison to be pixel by pixel. If a pixel by pixel comparison is hard, or even impossible, could you suggest a better way of doing this?

Comment: You can get image from database and image from webcam and find pixelwise difference value ( using absdiff function: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#absdiff ) but I don't think it will be very userful, because even two sequential frames of the same object taken from the same camera will not be absolutely same, because noise.

Comment: If you can make a coarse comparison (something like "these two images are from the same place but are not exactly the same"), you can try this library, that returns a score of how similar two images are: http://webdiis.unizar.es/~dorian/index.php?p=32

Answer (score 4):

A simple pixel by pixel comparison is unlikely to work well because of noise in the webcam image.

You need a similarity measure like [Peak signal-to-noise ratio (PSNR)](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-input-psnr-ssim/video-input-psnr-ssim.html#image-similarity-psnr-and-ssim) or [Structural Similarity (SSIM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity)

Comment: what if i change the live video stream to image to image pixel by pixel comparison?

Comment: @Paulina Jose   Sorry I didn't understand what you are proposing.

Comment: what method should i use if i am comparing 2 images pixel by pixel..
(The first image stored at a database and the second image is taken from a webcam..

Comment: @Paulina Jose the link I provided for PSNR on the OpenCV website actually has code to calculate both PSNR and SSIM. The best thing to do would be to try both methods, and any other alternatives you have come up with to see which works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) on your image and compare it with the precalculated image hash in the database.